Performance issues with grafana loki after upgraded to version 3.x
After upgrading to 3.0(enable TSDB) we are facing performance issues with loki. Queries are taking lots of time to complete.  Any help/config which can help to improve the query time.
Setup Details:
Loki Version: 3.1
Deployment Type: Loki Distributed
Ingesters: 7
Distributor: 7
index gateway: 3
Querier - autoscale
Frontend - autoscale
Scheduler - 5
Chunk/result cache - 3 each
Loki Configuration:
    auth_enabled: true
    chunk_store_config:
      cache_lookups_older_than: 2h
      chunk_cache_config:
        default_validity: 10m
        memcached:
          batch_size: 256
          expiration: 5m
          parallelism: 10
        memcached_client:
          addresses: dnssrv+_memcached-client._tcp.loki-distributed-memcached-chunks.logging.svc.cluster.local
          circuit_breaker_consecutive_failures: 10
          circuit_breaker_interval: 180s
          circuit_breaker_timeout: 180s
          consistent_hash: true
          max_item_size: 4845728
          timeout: 1000ms
      write_dedupe_cache_config:
        memcached_client:
          addresses: dnssrv+_memcached-client._tcp.loki-distributed-memcached-index-writes.logging.svc.cluster.local
          consistent_hash: true
    common:
      compactor_address: http://loki-distributed-compactor:3100
    compactor:
      delete_request_store: aws
      retention_delete_delay: 24h
      retention_delete_worker_count: 150
      retention_enabled: true
      working_directory: /var/loki/retention
    distributor:
      ring:
        kvstore:
          store: memberlist
    frontend:
      compress_responses: true
      grpc_client_config:
        grpc_compression: snappy
        max_recv_msg_size: 16777216000
        max_send_msg_size: 16777216000
      log_queries_longer_than: 5s
      querier_forget_delay: 10s
      scheduler_address: loki-distributed-query-scheduler:9095
      tail_proxy_url: http://loki-distributed-querier:3100
      scheduler_worker_concurrency: 20
    frontend_worker:
      grpc_client_config:
        grpc_compression: snappy
        max_recv_msg_size: 16777216000
        max_send_msg_size: 16777216000
      scheduler_address: loki-distributed-query-scheduler:9095
    index_gateway:
      mode: ring
      ring:
        kvstore:
          store: memberlist
    ingester:
      autoforget_unhealthy: true
      chunk_block_size: 262144
      chunk_encoding: snappy
      chunk_idle_period: 5m
      chunk_retain_period: 1m
      chunk_target_size: 3145728
      concurrent_flushes: 48
      flush_check_period: 15s
      lifecycler:
        ring:
          kvstore:
            store: memberlist
          replication_factor: 1
      max_chunk_age: 30m
      max_returned_stream_errors: 0
      wal:
        dir: /var/loki/wal
        enabled: true
        flush_on_shutdown: true
        replay_memory_ceiling: 4GB
    ingester_client:
      grpc_client_config:
        grpc_compression: snappy
        max_recv_msg_size: 16777216000
        max_send_msg_size: 16777216000
      pool_config:
        client_cleanup_period: 5s
        health_check_ingesters: true
    limits_config:
      allow_structured_metadata: false
      cardinality_limit: 400000
      deletion_mode: filter-and-delete
      ingestion_burst_size_mb: 148
      ingestion_rate_mb: 128
      ingestion_rate_strategy: global
      max_cache_freshness_per_query: 10m
      max_chunks_per_query: 5000000
      max_entries_limit_per_query: 10000
      max_global_streams_per_user: 20000
      max_label_names_per_series: 30
      max_line_size: 0
      max_querier_bytes_read: 150GB
      max_query_parallelism: 256
      max_query_series: 50000
      max_stats_cache_freshness: 0
      max_streams_matchers_per_query: 10000
      max_streams_per_user: 0
      per_stream_rate_limit: 30MB
      per_stream_rate_limit_burst: 50MB
      reject_old_samples: false
      retention_period: 8760h
      split_queries_by_interval: 15m
      tsdb_max_bytes_per_shard: 1000MB
      tsdb_max_query_parallelism: 1000
      tsdb_precompute_chunks: true
      unordered_writes: true
    memberlist:
      join_members:
      - loki-distributed-memberlist
    querier:
      engine:
        max_look_back_period: 30s
      max_concurrent: 10
      multi_tenant_queries_enabled: true
      query_ingesters_within: 1h
    query_range:
      align_queries_with_step: true
      cache_results: true
      max_retries: 1
      parallelise_shardable_queries: true
      results_cache:
        cache:
          memcached:
            batch_size: 1024
            expiration: 10m
            parallelism: 100
          memcached_client:
            addresses: dnssrv+_memcached-client._tcp.loki-distributed-memcached-frontend.logging.svc.cluster.local
            consistent_hash: true
            max_item_size: 4597152
            timeout: 500ms
            update_interval: 1m
    query_scheduler:
      max_outstanding_requests_per_tenant: 32768
      max_queue_hierarchy_levels: 0
      querier_forget_delay: 15s
    runtime_config:
      file: /var/loki-distributed-runtime/runtime.yaml
      period: 120s
    schema_config:
      configs:
      - from: "2020-09-07"
        index:
          period: 24h
          prefix: loki_index_
        object_store: aws
        schema: v11
        store: boltdb-shipper
      - from: "2024-07-14"
        index:
          period: 24h
          prefix: loki_index_
        object_store: s3
        schema: v12
        store: tsdb
      - from: "2024-07-15"
        index:
          period: 24h
          prefix: loki_index_
        object_store: s3
        schema: v13
        store: tsdb
    server:
      grpc_server_max_concurrent_streams: 10000
      grpc_server_max_recv_msg_size: 41943040000
      grpc_server_max_send_msg_size: 41943040000
      http_listen_port: 3100
      http_server_idle_timeout: 300s
      http_server_read_timeout: 300s
      http_server_write_timeout: 300s
    storage_config:
      aws:
        s3: s3://xxxxx
      boltdb_shipper:
        active_index_directory: /var/loki/index
        cache_location: /var/loki/cache
        cache_ttl: 24h
        index_gateway_client:
          server_address: dns:///loki-distributed-index-gateway:9095
      filesystem:
        directory: /var/loki/chunks
      index_cache_validity: 3m
      index_queries_cache_config:
        memcached:
          batch_size: 100
          expiration: 10m
          parallelism: 100
        memcached_client:
          addresses: dnssrv+_memcached-client._tcp.loki-distributed-memcached-index-queries.logging.svc.cluster.local
          consistent_hash: true
          timeout: 1000ms
      tsdb_shipper:
        active_index_directory: /var/loki/tsdb-index
        cache_location: /var/loki/tsdb-cache
        index_gateway_client:
          server_address: dns:///loki-distributed-index-gateway.logging.svc.cluster.local:9095

